# Spacing different in original html rendering vs dynamic JS rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a small part of my page:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="PolicyViolation(<%: ViewBag.DeviceData[i].DeviceID%>); return false;">
    <span class="policyViolationsNumber"><%= ViewBag.DeviceData[i].ViolationCount%></span>
    <span>Policy Violations</span>
 </a>
```

This renders out to have some space between the two spans.

In code, we update this in JS:

```
var spanViolationNumber = $('<span>')
                           .html(statusModel.Violations)
                           .addClass('policyViolationsNumber');
var spanViolationString = $('<span>')
               .html('<%=ServiceSite.Resources.Resources.DEVICES_POLICY_VIOLATIONS%>');
var imageTag = $('<img>')
                 .attr('src', '/Content/images/error_error.png')
                 .attr('align', 'absmiddle');
var anchorTag = $('<a href="#">')
                   .append(spanViolationNumber)
                   .append(spanViolationString);
cell.empty();
cell.append(imageTag)
    .append(anchorTag);
```

However, this renders out with no space between the spans. I've seen small issues like this before but never figured out what it is. You can ignore the image tag stuff, it is irrelevant.

EDIT:

Didn't know about this, I guess it's expected behaivor: http://jsfiddle.net/2MMuA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra space is happening because of the way you are formatting your HTML.

The "span" tag is an inline HTML element. This basically means you need to treat it just as you would treat text on the page.

```
<span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
<!-- Prints Hello World -->

<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
<!-- Prints Hello World
     The line break is where your extra space is coming from. -->

<span>Hello</span><span>World</span>
<!-- prints HelloWorld 
     This is how the ".append()" function is formatting the HTML.
     It adds it literally right after the last character in the HTML. -->
```

In order to normalize this across the two different techniques, you either have to butt your "span" tags right up next to each other so the HTML doesn't add an extra space...

```
<span></span><span></span>
```

..or you need to manually add the space in your ".append()" function.

```
obj.append(' ' + spanTag);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could clarify .. are you talking about there being space between these spans?

```
<span class="policyViolationsNumber">12</span>
<span>Policy Violations</span>
```

Either way I would look at adding some padding or margin to your css to insure you get the space that you want OR at minimum (though not recommended) use an HTML encoded space like so

```
&nbsp;
```

Comment: That is the span I'm referring to

Comment: then I would strongly recommend using css stlying rather than injecting spaces into the html

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely spaces between your spans. If you put the spans exactly next to each other then there should be no spaces.

```
<span></span><span></span>
```

Comment: Hmm, I mean, the span's are on the next line, but HTML shouldn't render any whitespace.